# Having Index of Replica of Docker container

Tags: docker, containers, load-balancing, replication

I need to scale a process and partition a group of work.

For example:

```
[1....1000] ids
```

I'd like to spin up 10 containers and have each container know it's 'index' so that it can partition is workload.

For example:

```
   container: worker (replicas 10)
   - worker(replica 1) processes ids 0-100
   - worker(replica 2) processes ids 100-200
   - etc, etc.
```

Possible?

Comment: You know [docker-swarm](https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/services/#replicated-or-global-services)? i guess with this its possible

Comment: I’d use a shell script and **seq**(1), or use a queueing system like RabbitMQ that didn’t depend on a static partitioning of the data.  Do you have a start on what you’ve done so far that you need help with?

Comment: I actually got it done. Instead, I created an API that sends groups of ids each request. That way the container doesn't need to register or partition, it just calls the API to get the next set of work.